# Creating AST's creates a stackoverflow error within rascal

Tags: rascal

I tried to create an AST from my big project (approximately 300k LOC). I did that in the following way:

```
for( file <- files(project)){

        map[Statement,map[str, list[int]]] duplicate = codeDuplicateMap(createAstFromFile(file, true)); 
        for(dup <- duplicate) {

            if(dup in dups) {
                dups[dup] = dups[dup] + duplicate[dup];
            } else {
                dups[dup] = duplicate[dup];
            }

        }

    }
```

Where `project` is an M3 project model, but I keep getting `|plugin://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/AST.rsc|(7496,375,<201,0>,<208,99>): Java("StackOverflowError","")`

I also tried to did it with `createAstFromEclipseProject('project://project-location')`, but that resulted in the same error.

How can I prevent this?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, but both your suggestions don't seem to help. It still throws a Stackoverflow Error.

`|plugin://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/AST.rsc|(7496,375,<201,0>,<208,99>): Java("StackOverflowError","")
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(|unknown:///HashMap.java|(0,0,<338,0>,<338,0>))
        at java.util.HashMap.get(|unknown:///HashMap.java|(0,0,<556,0>,<556,0>))
        at org.rascalmpl.value.type.TypeStore.lookupConstructor(|unknown:///TypeStore.java|(0,0,<485,0>,<485,0>))
        at org.rascalmpl.value.type.TypeStore.lookupConstructor(|unknown:///TypeStore.java|(0,0,<547,0>,<547,0>))`

I also increased my stack to 128m without any result either.

Comment: https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/735 is the bug that is associated with this which was resolved this morning thanks also to your message. You can update your Rascal installation by changing `stable` to `unstable` in the URL of the Rascal update site and you can work like that. Alternatively you could call `createAstFromFile(file, false)` (false instead of true) to work around the problem but than you get less information.

Comment: I tested the `false` argument and that really circumvents the issue for me.

Comment: Hi Jurgen, I had a strange problem with Eclipse where my changes weren't being saved to disk. Therefore I ran my initial code each time. I will test it again tonight and report my findings. Thanks for your reaction.

Comment: Ok, I confirmed it works now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running into the same problem (which in my case was not solved by increasing the stack size), I found that setting the collectBindings argument to `false` prevents the stack overflow at the cost of some information in the resulting AST.

Detailed info (from Jurgen) on what collectBindings does can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397593/rascal-what-does-the-bool-collectbindings-in-creating-ast-do)

Comment: This helps. Now we can look for a bug in the code activated by that option :-)

Comment: bug was fixed. So you can try an unstable release if you need the bindings.

Comment: Thanks all. Now testing it out. I will report my results later. I'm currently not on the unstable build. I added -vmargs -Xmx1G -Xss128m to eclipse.ini and gave a `false` argument to createAstFromFile.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bouke. It works like a charm now.